# MongoDB 2 - query array without hardcoding name

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an Issue entity with contains a List of Guids named AssignedTo. For one ID, I need to retrieve all issues with that ID inside AssignedTo list/array

So far I've managed doing this with:

```
var filter = Builders<Issue>.Filter.Eq("AssignedTo", id.ToString());
return await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

but I do not want to hardcore AssignedTo in the query. p => p.AssignedTo does not work, I've tried that too.

Also, how do I tell to BsonClassMap to register that list as a list of strings and not GUIDS? I know about this:

```
x.GetMemberMap(p => p.AssignedBy).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
```

but how I do it on lists?

I'm using the latest MongoDB driver for C#. (2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the AnyEq method. See the docs here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/#array-operators

```
var filter = Builders<Issue>.Filter.AnyEq(x => x.AssignedTo, id.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but without .ToString(). But how do I serialize this so that inserts strings and not guids?

Comment: First question: Why do you want to store them as strings? Strings will take up a lot more space that storing them as a Guid.

Second: you need to set the serializer for the list instead of the items. Unfortunately, that name sucks. new ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<TEntity, List<TEntity>>(entitySerializer);